# Need to update new column created on table with data processed from same table

Tags: oracle

```
update UC_OFCOM_HIST_TRANS_LOG 
set LOAD_DATE_TIME = ( 
  select to_char(to_date(substr(
    a.file_name,
    instr(a.file_name , '',1,4)+1,
    length(a.file_name)-instr(a.file_name,'',1,4)-4
  ),'YYYYMMDDHH24MiSS'),'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:Mi:SS)                         
  from UC_OFCOM_HIST_TRANS_LOG a
);
```

getting an error:

> ORA-01427 Single-row subquery returns more than one row

Comment: What is `a` in those `a.file_name` references?

Comment: What is the datatype of `LOAD_DATE_TIME` ?

Comment: a is alias  and datatype is date() . i have edited the code added a now

Comment: "Single-row subquery returns more than one row" seems to be pretty clear. Does `UC_OFCOM_HIST_TRANS_LOG ` only have one row in it?? Perhaps you meant `update UC_OFCOM_HIST_TRANS_LOG set LOAD_DATE_TIME = to_char(to_date( substr(file_name, instr(file_name , '', 1, 4) + 1, length(file_name) - instr(file_name, '', 1, 4) - 4), 'YYYYMMDDHH24MiSS'), 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:Mi:SS');`

Comment: if there are so many  rows what logic can be used  could you please give a hint

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why this popped up for me now, but ... what you are doing is updating column `LOAD_DATE_TIME` for each row in `UC_OFCOM_HIST_TRANS_LOG` with the computed value based on the `FILE_NAME` column from every row in `UC_OFCOM_HIST_TRANS_LOG`.

This is why, if there is more than one row in `UC_OFCOM_HIST_TRANS_LOG`, you get `ORA-01427`.

@Charlieface has rewritten you update so that each row is updated by the computed value of `FILE_NAME` from that individual row.

I would also ask:

- why you have `LOAD_DATE_TIME` as (apparently) `VARCHAR2` as `DATE` would seem more appropriate?
- if it must be `VARCHAR` then why not use ISO format date (`yyyymmdd`)?
- why have `instr (file_name, '', 1, 4)` when it returns a null string?